# Need help formatting data entered in form when transferring to database

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form in Excel using VBA that records information users input from meetings and puts it in a database. One of the most important data pieces I'm collecting is the decisions made during the meeting, and a tag that goes along with it (Easy decision, big change impact, loud dissenters, and close vote). I want the information to be formatted into the database like this:
[image]

Is there a way to write VBA code that will format the database this way? I have a variable that counts the number of decisions inputted by the user, so I'm hoping there's a way to use that integer to merge the correct number of cells together for the council's name. I'm new to VBA and a bit lost. Hopefully this description makes sense.... any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the save code I have so far. I haven't changed it to try to implement my ideas above because I'm not sure where to start. The two commented out lines (iRow, 4 and iRow, 5) are from before I added the option to submit multiple decisions.

Sub Save(decisionCount As Integer)

```
Dim frm As Worksheet
Dim database As Worksheet

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iSerial As Long

Set frm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")
Set database = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

If Trim(frm.Range("M1").Value) = "" Then
    iRow = database.Range("A" & Application.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    If iRow = 2 Then
        
        iSerial = 1
    
    Else
    
        iSerial = database.Cells(iRow - 1, 1).Value + 1
    
    End If

Else
    iRow = frm.Range("L1").Value
    iSerial = frm.Range("M1").Value
    
End If


With database

    .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = iSerial
    .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = frm.Range("I6").Value
    .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = frm.Range("I8").Value
    '.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = frm.Range("I13").Value
    '.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = frm.Range("I15").Value
    .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = frm.Range("I24").Value
    .Cells(iRow, 7).Value = frm.Range("I29").Value
    .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = frm.Range("I34").Value
    .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = frm.Range("I39").Value
    .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Application.UserName
    .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = [Text(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")]

End With

frm.Range("L1").Value = ""
frm.Range("M1").Value = ""
```

End Sub

This is the code that I have written to record the decisions inputted by the user:
Sub SubmitDecision()

```
Dim frm As Worksheet
'Dim decisionCount As Integer

Set frm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")

'Checking which decision cell is open
If Trim(frm.Range("E19").Value) = "" Then
    frm.Range("E19").Value = frm.Range("I13").Value
    frm.Range("I19").Value = frm.Range("I15").Value
    
    Call decisionCount(1)
    
    'Clearing decisions made by council cell and decision tags cell
    frm.Range("I13").Interior.Color = xlNone
    frm.Range("I13").Value = ""
    
    frm.Range("I15").Interior.Color = xlNone
    frm.Range("I15").Value = ""

ElseIf Trim(frm.Range("E20").Value) = "" Then
    frm.Range("E20").Value = frm.Range("I13").Value
    frm.Range("I20").Value = frm.Range("I15").Value
    
    Call decisionCount(2)
    
    'Clearing decisions made by council cell
    frm.Range("I13").Interior.Color = xlNone
    frm.Range("I13").Value = ""
    
    frm.Range("I15").Interior.Color = xlNone
    frm.Range("I15").Value = ""

ElseIf Trim(frm.Range("E21").Value) = "" Then
    frm.Range("E21").Value = frm.Range("I13").Value
    frm.Range("I21").Value = frm.Range("I15").Value
    
    Call decisionCount(3)
    
    'Clearing decisions made by council cell
    frm.Range("I13").Interior.Color = xlNone
    frm.Range("I13").Value = ""
    
    frm.Range("I15").Interior.Color = xlNone
    frm.Range("I15").Value = ""

ElseIf Trim(frm.Range("E22").Value) = "" Then
    frm.Range("E22").Value = frm.Range("I13").Value
    frm.Range("I22").Value = frm.Range("I15").Value
    
    Call decisionCount(4)
    
    'Clearing decisions made by council cell
    frm.Range("I13").Interior.Color = xlNone
    frm.Range("I13").Value = ""
    
    frm.Range("I15").Interior.Color = xlNone
    frm.Range("I15").Value = ""
End If
```

End Sub

And here is what the form looks like:
[image]

When the user clicks submit decision, the decision is populated in the table below and the entry fields are cleared.

Comment: What database are you loading?  Excel is not a database.

Comment: Sorry, I said database, but I'm just transferring the data to another sheet in the workbook

Comment: You haven't shared any of your code, so it's difficult for anyone to suggest any changes.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added my code in. Does that help?